# Hibernate mapping, on a unmapped class

Tags: hibernate, mapping, entities, hibernate-onetomany

I' ve got 2 tables... Challenge and ChallengeYear, ChallengeYear is only to create a list of years in challenge.

I only want to make Challenge an entity, containing a list of List years. Is this possible?

I've looked in to @SecondaryTable together with @JoinColumn and @OneToMany, but neither of those can do the trick, or i am overlooking something.

Can someone help me?

Greetings,
Jan

Comment: and how do you expect these to be persisted in the database? What does ChallangeYear contain? Is it only an integer containing the year, or there is more?

Comment: it should be persisted like a @OneToMany(CascadeType.ALL, FetchType.EAGER) ChallengeYear contains a FK constraint to the Challenge and then a column year. So that it's possible to add several years to a challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is Year in your model, is it an Integer ?

if yes, you may annotate your Challenge.getYears method with @CollectionOfElements

like:

```
  @CollectionOfElements
  @JoinTable(
    table=@Table(name="ChallengeYear"),
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="challengeId")
  )
  @Column(name="year", nullable=false)
  List<Integer> getYears() {
    ...
```

Comment: works great, thank you, i've came across the @CollectionOfElements annotation, but didn't know how to configure it. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @Jan - if this answer worked for you, mark it as accepted (the tick below the vote counter)

Comment: @Jan: my pleasure... the hibernate mapping reference documentation can be a tough reading

@Bozho: Thx ;-)